# DOCKER: npm ERR! missing script: start

Tags: node.js, docker, npm

Every time I enter `docker-compose up` in the terminal I get this error:

```
blogapp | npm ERR! missing script: start
blogapp | 
blogapp | npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
blogapp | npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-10-28T08_54_29_180Z-debug.log
blogapp exited with code 1
```

I get it multiple times before I exit out of the application.
This is my package.json:

```
    "name": "blogapp",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "blog app",
    "main": "app.js",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "start": "node app.js"
    },
    "author": "me",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "@material/button": "^7.0.0",
        "ejs": "^3.1.5",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "mongoose": "^5.10.9",
        "morgan": "^1.10.0"
    }
}
```

Please help me get to the root of this problem.
Do let me know if you need me to share any other files or information.

--x--

Edit:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:latest

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

and docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
    app:
        container_name: blogapp
        restart: always
        build: .
        ports:
            - '80:3000'
        links:
            - mongo
    mongo:
        container_name: mongoDB
        image: mongo
        ports:
            - '27017:27017'
```

Also, I can't figure out how to access my debug logs (first-timer) so please help me with that too.

Comment: can you share the docker-compose.yml or the Dockerfile? (depending on where you define the command to start the container)

Comment: It looks like it cannot find the package.json file. Make sure it was either copied with the COPY command in the coresponding Dockerfile or it is mounted on the right path within your docker-compose.yaml file.

Comment: @ErikMüller he would have sent an `ENOENT` error if that was the case.

Comment: @Stefano You're right. My bad. So it just cannot find the app.js file. Maybe the blogapp files are not copied or mounted properly.

Comment: I have edited the question to add the Dockerfile as well as the docker-container.yml... You can have a look at them.

Answer (score -1):

Please make sure, that you set the correct start file and also make sure that you don't have multiple "start" scripts. If that doesn't help, please post the given log under `/root/.npm/_logs/2020-10-28T08_54_29_180Z-debug.log`

Comment: I think this should be a comment and not an answer.